# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError with Ruby's open method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm trying to get an https page with Ruby's `open` method:

```
response = open("https://example.com", 'User-Agent' => 'somebot').read
```

Sometimes it succeeds, but sometimes I get this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
```

What's the reason this is happening and how come for some websites it works and for some it doesn't?

Comment: So this is related solely to AWS?

Comment: The intermittent failure is unusual. We need more information. Please discuss the operational environments for success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the error message:

```
error: certificate verify failed
```

When you connect to some server using secure connection (https), all certificates in the certificate chain are checked for their validity up to the root certificate. If any of the certificates in the chain does not pass validity or the root certificate is not trusted root certificate, you get that error.

If you are on OSX and use RVM, see this [readme](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/help/osx-ssl-certs.md). Alternatively, read about the issue [here](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).